# angular - only import what a module needs

Tags: angular, import, module, export

Assume, I have modules called **ModuleA** and **ModuleB**

**ModuleA** exports **ComponentA**, **DirectiveA** and **PipeA**

**ModuleB** declares **ComponentB**

Let's say I need to use **DirectiveA** inside **ComponentB**. So I import **ModuleA** into **ModuleB**. By doing this **ModuleB** can use (available) all exported components, directives, pipes from **ModuleA**. But I need one and only one item from ModuleA (here it is **DirectiveA**).

So I would like to know is there way to import just a one declared/exported item from **ModuleA** rather than importing the whole module itself into **ModuleB**?

Comment: see this :https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#example-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put DirectiveA into its own shared module so that it can be imported into any module that needs it without sharing other things you don't want to share.